# Nice Scoll Jquery not Working in in Mobile Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-mobile, nicescroll

i added nice scroll to my site thats working in all of browser nicely but slightly not working in Mobile `Chrome` just stacked user cannot able to scroll or to do any think ,i tried more version of `Nice Scroll Js`

Answer (score 2):

It happens to me when the `body` is set to `overflow: hidden;`, the issue gone away when I remove the `overflow: hidden;` from `body`

Cheers